# Express.js with Foundation for Apps

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, zurb-foundation

I am trying to set up the Express.js web framework to use with the foundation for apps architecture.  I am relatively new to the Node world.

What changes must I make to the gulpfile.js, and app.js to get this up and running? I would imagine the use of gulp-express dependency can come in handy, but there is so much going on that I don't know what would break.

Relevant code:

package.json:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
     "start": "gulp"
},
"devDependencies": {
  ...
}
```

app.js (Don't know how to tie these together..):

```
 var express = require('express');
 var app = module.exports.app = exports.app = express();
 app.use(require('connect-livereload')());

(function() {
  'use strict';

  var myApplication = angular.module('TODO', [
    'ui.router',
    'ngAnimate',
    'foundation.core',
    ...
```

gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = ...
           ...
var server = require('gulp-express');

gulp.task('server:start', function() {
// connect.server({
//   root: './build',
//   middleware: function() {
//     return [
//       modRewrite(['^[^\\.]*$ /index.html [L]'])
//     ];
//   },
// });
   server.run({
     root: './build',
     file: './build/assets/js/app.js'
   });
});
```

FileStructure:

```
build/
   ...
client/
   -assets/
      -img/
      -scss/
      -js/
         -app.js
node_modules/
   ...
bower.json
Gemfile
Gemfile.lock
gulpfile.js
package.json
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked through this small tut once upon a time, this would be a good place to start for node / express and should give you the basic idea of how it hangs together (easier than me trying to explain it anyway):

http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/

I would also recommend checking out the express API guide on their website.

Comment: This answer's link doesn't contain any reference to the foundation library, or apparently the problems experienced by the OP.